# Response from OData API in .NetCore is well formed?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, odata, httpresponsemessage

I have this function code made in a controller `CustomEntityController` of a `CustomEntity` Model from OData API

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] CustomEntity entity)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;


    SecurityController sc = new SecurityController();
    // if (sc.CheckPermission(User.Identity.Name, "CustomEntity", "Write")) {
    if (sc.CheckPermission("User", "CustomEntity", "Write"))
    {
        _context.CustomEntity.Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(entity.ToString());
        response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {

            Content = stringContent
        };
        response.Headers.Add("Location", string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/CustomEntity", HttpContext.Request.Host.Host, HttpContext.Request.Host.Port));
    }

    return response;
}
```

When a client wants to create a `CustomEntity`, it calls the `Post` function. All works fine on the API server side, the entity is added to data base associated in `_context`. But when i use the Post from a client, the client throws me an error

> 500 (Internal Server Error).

The response is badly formed?

This is the client code:

```
Container cont;
cont = new Container(new Uri("http://localhost:51342/")); 
cont.Credentials = credentials;


CustomEntity lr = new CustomEntity();
lr.AreaPath = "AreaPath";
lr.Description = "Description";
lr.Frecuency = "Frecuency";
lr.Name = "Name";
lr.Reason ="Reason";
lr.RequestArea = "RequestArea";
cont.AddToCustomEntity(lr);
cont.SaveChanges(); //throws an InternalServerError
```